# Q PHP $_SESSION not working on CPANEL

Tags: php, session, cpanel

```
$_SESSION Not working on CPANEL.
```

When we uploaded it to the web host using `CPANEL` the `$_SESSION` is not working. 
**But in local using XAMPP it is working.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [session\_start not working properly in cpanel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17335112/session-start-not-working-properly-in-cpanel)

Comment: Hi @Ravi thanks for the comment we only call the session_start once. is there any stuff that make cpanel get the session? or is there a button to enable session in cpanel?

Comment: The problem is your header is not being set. Please follow suggested link and your problem will be resolved.

Comment: at the top of your page add `ob_start();` then `session_start();`

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile still not working.

Comment: @RaviHirani i will try it. thank you a lot.

Comment: what does your `php_info()` does it show 
**Session Support enabled** ? @ChristianReyBaron

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Hi sir, php_info() not displaying :(. But in xampp all of that code is working. but in cpanel, so hopeless.

Comment: Write `phpinfo();`

Comment: at the top of any page just type what @RaviHirani have typed then save and refresh that page on the browser then scroll down to **session**

Comment: I did sir. but the browser doesnt load at all after i code phpinfo(); but in local using xampp its working

Comment: which hosting company are you using? try lodge a ticket they might assist

Comment: hi there. thanks for the comment. the problem already solve by removing html on the top. thanks guys.

Comment: it's possibility that sessions either aren't enabled or aren't configured correctly in the php.ini file on your server.

Comment: Hi sir, already solve the problem. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! the problem is, I put all my session on other php file so when include the php I put it under the html code.
I mean like this:

```
<html> <?php ?> </html>
```

so when I update it to this

```
<?php ?> <html>
```

all stuff are good. thanks for the comment guys <3

Answer (score 2):

`Sessions` are enabled by default within any PHP installations and hence do not need any special configuration to enable sessions.

You should make sure you have `session_start();` as the first line in any page where you want to use sessions; it should be the very first line, before any whitespace (an empty line, for example).

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you for your advise sir. already solved. many thanks to all of your help guys!

Answer (score 1):

you have make sure to write  `<?php session_start();?>` in the first line of page

Comment: Voting down as this was already answer in 2017 by multiple users. Adding more duplicate answers isn't productive.

Answer (score 0):

you should insert session_start() in the beginning of the script. 
Make confirm you call it on every page you need the access to session variables as well

Comment: Thank you for your advise sir.

Answer (score -1):

Place your session_start() at top of your page or header before the actual html

Comment: Thanks for contributing, but this is already mentioned in existing answers. Please take time to read, before adding your own.